# SQL SELECT ... WHERE IN with separate LIMIT,OFFSET clause

Tags: sql, postgresql, where-in

I have simple SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM t1 
WHERE status = 1 AND user_id = ? AND some_field NOT IN (?, ?, ..., ?)
ORDER BY createdAt DESC, rating DESC
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0;
```

But I want to perform similar query for collection of users without cycle in my PHP code. Looks like I need to use IN clause in user_id = ? condition (user_id IN (?,...?)) and separate LIMIT,OFFSET clauses for each id in user_id IN clause. I know that is not possible, but maybe exists any workarounds without drop a performance of my query?

I use PostgreSQL 9.0.3 and I assume possibility of using stored procedure for solving this problem too.

Comment: First: 9.0.3?!? You're behind on many important patch releases including a critical security update. Upgrade now. See http://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/, http://www.postgresql.org/support/security/faq/2013-04-04/

Comment: As for the question its self, I'm finding it hard to figure out what exactly the problem is, what problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: I don't get the problem at all, do you trying to get data by 10 rows or what?

Comment: Now I have N separate queires with user_id = YYY clause with same LIMIT,OFFSET condition on every such query. Retrieved data is aggregated into single collection on PHP side. But I want to form resulting collection directly on DB side without any cycles on PHP side and ommit it as single query result or stored procedure call result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select *
from (
    select *,
        row_number() over(
            partition by user_id
            order by createdat desc, rating desc
        ) as rn
    from t1 
    where
        status = 1 and some_field not in (?, ?, ..., ?)
        and user_id in (1,2,3)
) s
where rn <= 10
order by user_id, rn
```

Window functions:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-window.html

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-WINDOW-FUNCTIONS

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html

Comment: Looks like a magic! Try to use it. And what about performance of this query?

Comment: @Ostrovski Window functions are expensive. To learn a bit more about postgresql query costs look for `explain`

Comment: Oh, it is too slowly. My cyclic selects it's about 10 times faster even I do it consequently in separate queries.

Comment: @Ostrovski If you limit the user_id the cost is greatly reduced. Check the updated answer.

Comment: Faster but still a few hundreds of milliseconds too.